# Way to "free-hand" draw shapes in shiny?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, drawing, rendering

Is there a function or some other way to enable free-hand drawing (i.e., drawing of random shapes/sizes) using the mouse in Shiny?

Specifically, I'd like to be able to "interact" with a plot from `renderPlot` by marking it in various (but non-uniform) ways. --  In other words, I want to be able to mark-up already existing graphics.

The shortcomings of functions I *have* found include:

1. Tools for drawing points, lines, rectangles, or circles are not flexible enough for me.
2. Tools are not always compatible with a `click_plot` interaction kind of set-up.

Comment: Hi have you thought accepting any answer for this question?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64334711/9841389) is another way using `plotly`.

Answer (score 18):

Using only basic `shiny` functionnalities, you can build an app where you can draw manual shapes upon a simple plot. I use the base `plot` function here so it reacts quicker. It uses both click and hover parameters of the `plotOutput`. If you want to do it on a more complex, preexisting plot, you might prefer ggplot to better manage the different layers? You can also think of adding a spline smoother to the points.  Visual:

[image]

Code of the app :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Click on plot to start drawing, click again to pause"),
  sliderInput("mywidth", "width of the pencil", min=1, max=30, step=1, value=10),
  actionButton("reset", "reset"),
  plotOutput("plot", width = "500px", height = "500px",
             hover=hoverOpts(id = "hover", delay = 100, delayType = "throttle", clip = TRUE, nullOutside = TRUE),
             click="click"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  vals = reactiveValues(x=NULL, y=NULL)
  draw = reactiveVal(FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$click, handlerExpr = {
    temp <- draw(); draw(!temp)
    if(!draw()) {
      vals$x <- c(vals$x, NA)
      vals$y <- c(vals$y, NA)
    }})
  observeEvent(input$reset, handlerExpr = {
    vals$x <- NULL; vals$y <- NULL
  })
  observeEvent(input$hover, {
    if (draw()) {
      vals$x <- c(vals$x, input$hover$x)
      vals$y <- c(vals$y, input$hover$y)
    }})
  output$plot= renderPlot({
    plot(x=vals$x, y=vals$y, xlim=c(0, 28), ylim=c(0, 28), ylab="y", xlab="x", type="l", lwd=input$mywidth)
  })}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope it helps..
Late note: I have another question on this subject, to allow compatibility of this code with smartphone movements. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56804019/3871924).

Comment: any suggestions to how you might do this with ggplot? This was the best I could come up with, but it doesn't sit right with me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309573/rshiny-freehand-drawing-ggplot-how-to-improve-and-or-format-for-plotly

Comment: Hey @agenis, I wonder if it is possible to do this if you were trying to work with an image (e.g. a jpg/png file). e.g. I am currently using ggplot2's ggdraw() method to render the image; however, I'm unable to draw on the image. I think I saw you also asking if you were able to save the location of the points drawn on the image as a list. I am also curious if you found a solution to this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an idea using `shinyjs` and [Signature Pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad), adapting the demo for "drawing over an image".

1. Save a copy of [signature_pad.js](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/blob/v1.5.3/signature_pad.js) in the "wwww" sub-directory of your app directory (you'll need to create this folder if you haven't already). [This subdirectory is a special folder](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). I used the latest release of Signature Pad, v1.5.3.
2. Create a CSS file with the below code and place the file in the main app directory.
3. Use `shinyjs` to run the JavaScript function when the page loads. Read about using `shinyjs::extendShinyjs` [here](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/blob/master/vignettes/shinyjs-extend.Rmd). Note from the vignette that package `V8` should be installed.

**CSS**

```
.signature-pad {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**App**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "shinyjs.init = function() {

var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
  penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
});
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
var cancelButton = document.getElementById('clear');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');

// Send data to server instead...
  window.open(data);
});

cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  signaturePad.clear();
});

}"

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    df <- sample_frac(diamonds, 0.1)

    ggplot(df, aes(x = carat, y = price, color = color)) +
      geom_point()

  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  includeCSS("custom.css"),
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "signature_pad.js")),

  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = jscode),

  h1("Draw on plot"),
  div(class="wrapper",
      plotOutput("plot1"),
      HTML("<canvas id='signature-pad' class='signature-pad' width=600 height=400></canvas>"),
      HTML("<div>
           <button id='save'>Save</button>
           <button id='clear'>Clear</button>
           </div>")

  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like exactly what I wanted! However, I'm new to all of this...what's the www directory?

Comment: (my assumption was to create a folder in my wd called "www" and save a copy of the .js file in it.). If that's correct, I got the plot to graph from your demo, but I gain no ability to draw....

Comment: @theforestecologist you are correct the "www" directory goes in the main app directory. I tried to clarify the steps a bit above.

Comment: thanks. So I copied and saved the signature_pad.js code to a file called "signature_pad.js" in a "www" folder in my wd, copied your css code and saved it as "custom.css" in my wd, installed all packages you have listed (+ V8), and copied/ran your code as written. The ggplot graphic shows up as do the "save" and "clear" buttons. But I have no ability to actually draw. .... what am I missing??

Comment: are you sure no other packages are needed? I've tried repeatedly to get this code to work, but the signature-pad just doesn't seem to work for me (specifically, the mouse does not draw anything). Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like you've got it. What browser are you using? Can you run the app and email me your devtools::session_info() results at the address in my profile? Also include your app.R, .css, and .js files.

Comment: Sent. though it's been bounced back a few times, so let me know if my most recent attempt went through

Comment: Hey, never heard back...did you ever find out anything from the stuff I sent you?

Comment: @theforestecologist Sorry, schedule was very busy. When I run the app with your code and files, it works. The only difference in the session info is that I'm running one version later of R (3.3.2), but I'm not sure if that should make a difference.

Comment: I've come back to this to try again. Even with all new versions of R (3.4.0), R Studio (1.0.143), shiny (1.0.3), shinyjs (0.9.1), signature_pad (2.2.0), etc., I still can't get this to work. I've tried to follow your directions exactly, but no luck. Could you perhaps show a screen shot of the files in your directory?? I *have* to be misunderstanding *something* since it works for you but not for me!!

Comment: **5 other people upvoted this. Can any of you comment on whether this approach worked for you or not?** I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: FYI: I can get the canvas to work (I found out by adding a style argument and modifying the canvas) and I can get the buttons to physically appear. In other words, the html and R stuff work fine. However, nothing I seem to do to the jscode script causes anything to *actually* show up on my app. (the buttons likewise do nothing). I've tried and been unsuccessful in RStudio, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: Hi @VanceLopez thanks for this post. I'm looking for a way to retrieve the drawing, either as a list of data points or as an exported image. The save button does not seem to work, and if I use a ggsave function it returns just the plot without the drawing. Thanks

Comment: It worked for me, except the save button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 7):

Small example with an `iframe` using `draw.io` online tools

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Getting Started with draw.io"), htmlOutput("frame"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src="https://www.draw.io", height=1000, width=1400)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really great tool (+1)! I'll have to remember this one. However, I'm looking for a tool that let's me draw more "free-hand"...Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like `draw.io` is limited to preconceived shapes (i.e., squares, lines, circles, etc.). I want to be able to "scribble." Also, I'm preferably looking for something that let's me mark up already existing graphics -- such as jotting a quick note on an existing plot.

Comment: @Pork, can you help me on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583493/draw-circle-on-vis-network-canvas-and-arrange-nodes?noredirect=1#comment116499307_65583493) ?